# Websphere 8.5.5.3 OSGi: adding and updating bundles

Tags: websphere, osgi

I have Websphere 8.5.5.3 available and a tech design task at hand.

Assuming that an OSGi Application has no dependency on any bundles from the OSGi bundle repository (i.e., is self contained in terms of bundle dependencies). And assuming that the application is up and running on the Websphere, can I:

1. Add and start a new bundle to the running application without restarting the application (other bundles).
2. Update the application with a new version of a bundle that is already deployed as a part of application without restarting the application (other bundles)

I went through IBM's resources on OSGi apps in Websphere and I don't seem to be able to find how do I go about it.....

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am answering my own question after more research, this is mostly comming from this resource and poking around the Websphere admin console (aka integrated solution console):

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCKBL_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.osgi.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/thread_ta_extend.html?lang=en

Assuming there's an OSGi application deployed and running on Websphere and assuming you have access to Websphere web based admin console:

**To update a bundle to newer version**, you have to:

1. Deploy the new version of the bundle into internal OSGi bundle repository.
   (Environment -> OSGi Bundle Repositories -> Internal bundle repository)
2. Update a version of the bundle in the application
   (Applications -> Application Types -> Assets -> [your.eba asset] -> Update bundle versions in this application) then choose the version from dropdown next to the bundle and then click 'Preview' and then 'Create'
3. Update the application to use the latest configuration
   (Applications -> Applicationtypes -> Business-level applications -> [your application] -> [your eba] -> Update to latest deployment)

**To add a new bundle to the application**, you have to:

1. Create a **composite bundle** containing/referencing the new bundles you wish to add to your application (CBA file)
2. Deploy that bundle to the internal bundle repository
   (Environment -> OSGi Bundle Repositories -> Internal bundle repository)
3. Register that bundle as an extension to your application
   (Applications -> Application Types -> Business-level applications -> [your application] -> [your eba] -> Extensions for this composition unit -> Add)
4. Update the application to use the latest configuration
   (Applications -> Applicationtypes -> Business-level applications -> [your application] -> [your eba] -> Update to latest deployment)